# Twitter Rest APIのアクセストークンの再取得は必要でしょうか？

Tags: php, twitter

OAuth認証の時にGETで取得したアクセストークンに必要な情報を使いまわしたいと考えています。

一度認証を行うと、「oauth_token」と「oauth_verifier」をGETで取得することができ、
その値を元にアクセストークンを取得して、ユーザー情報を取得できます。

そのため、一度取得した「oauth_token」と「oauth_verifier」をSessionに保存して、
自動投稿するページ毎にその値でユーザー情報を取得して、tweetを行いたいです。

例えば、サービス無いでツイート内容を選べて、かつ、複数回ツイート出来るようにしたい場合、
毎回認証を挟まずに済むのであれば、アクセストークンの取得を最初のOAuth認証だけで集約できるので効率的です。

しかし、実際に実装すると、sessionに保存した情報ではアクセストークンが取得できません。

Twitterでは、投稿毎に、毎回OAuth認証をでコールバックさせる事が必要なのでしょうか？
その都度、Twitterでアプリケーションの連携画面を出さないようにすることはできないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

（どのラッパーライブラリ等を利用されているのかは知りませんが、）

`oauth_token`はアクセストークン取得のためのワンタイムトークンになります。（ので当然再利用はできませんし、アクセストークンを取得したら破棄しましょう）

一度アクセストークンの取得までたどり着けたら、そこでセッションに持つべきなのはアクセストークン（およびそれのペアのsecret）です。

Answer (score -1):

ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
情報不足で大変失礼しました。

なるほど、アクセストークンを保持するのですね。
アクセストークンを再利用して、投稿することが出来ました。
ご回答いただきありがとうございます。

Comment: お礼は参考になった回答に対してコメントを付けるか、回答を「承認済み」にしてあげてください。お礼コメントを「回答」として投稿するのは適切ではありません。ぜひヘルプも一度参照してみてください。 - [回答が削除される理由は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)